# Issues with SearchVIew in Recycler Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am working on on an app that keeps track of someones expenses, the user adds what they have purchased and it keeps track of that, the expenses are displayed in a recyclerview, there comes a time when one has too many items and needs to search hence I added a search functionality which is working just find, but because am dealing with expenses the adapter has a check box which indicate if or not an expense has been paid for, when I search for an item and tick it to have been paid for the feature works fine but as soon as i exit search mode I notice something, the item goes back to its original position in list but the item that occupies the position the previously modified item also inherits the paid state, it is ticked as paid for as well, Hopefully my explanation makes sense, here are some screen shots to demonstrate what I mean:

in the first screen shot we have a normal list but I will search for `Dgdf`currently `Dgdf` is at position `1`

[image]

After search for `Dgdf`it takes position `0` in the array

[image]

Since I have the item I was looking for which in this case is `Dgdf` I decide to mark it as paid for which I do

[image]

but here is the issue as soon as I exist edit-mode item that takes position `0` is also ticked as paid for

[image]

Below is my code that am using for searching:

```
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<Expense> results = new ArrayList<>();

            //I thought loading new data from database each time would
            // help but did not help at all
            filterSearch = database.getAllExpenses();
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (filterSearch != null & filterSearch.size() > 0)
                {
                    for (Expense g : filterSearch)
                        if (g.getMerchantName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            results.add(g);
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
            }
            return oReturn;
        }


@Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            //update adapter arraylist
            adapterExpenseList = (ArrayList<Expense>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
```

Comment: Obviously you shouldn't use position but some id ... so error is not with filtering but in storing the check state of item ... the easy way it would be store if item is check in `Expense` model itself - or ids in some SpraseArray

Comment: Selvin yes, you are right, storing them in the model would work and that is what am doing, apparently its not working, I tried to call invalidate on the recycler and I noticed all Items were check, issues is coming in when I call `notifydatasetchanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, apparently all was alright with the search algorithm, the issue was the code responsible for ticking the checkboxes, I was checking only one side, that is,

```
      if (expense.getIsChecked() == 1)
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true); 
      else 
       holder.checkBox.setChecked(false)
```

But at the time I was performing this check the checkbox was already set to true hence there was no way of unchecking it, so I just did this

```
 if (expense.getIsChecked() == 1)
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);


    if (expense.getIsChecked() == 0)
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

I had to check for both occurrences, whether or not it was true or false, and it works just fine now.